# Bezout's Identity and the sign of coefficients

Tags: elementary-number-theory, first-order-logic

My problem regards working with Bezout's Identity in first order number theory.  That is, I can only work with natural numbers (i.e. positive integers).

Bezout's Identity states that for any natural numbers $a,b$ with common divisor $d$, there exist integers $x,y$ such that $xa + yb = d$.  Now because $a,b$ are natural numbers $x$ and $y$ must have different signs.  Furthermore, there are two pairs of $x_k,y_k$ with swapped signs that satisfy the equation.  That is, both $x_1 a + y_1 b = d$ and $x_2 a + y_2 b = d$ where in one equation the $x_k$ is positive and the $y_k$ is negative and in the other equation $x_k$ is negative and $y_k$ is positive.

Now to translate this into the language of natural numbers we have that there exist $s_1, t_1$ such that $s_1a = t_1b + d$ and there exist $s_2, t_2$ such that $t_2b = s_2a + d$.  However, I have only been able to show the disjunction of this statement.  That is either there are coefficients such that $s_1a = t_1b + d$ OR there are coefficients such that $t_2b = s_2a + d$.

My question is: Is there a process to go from one equation to the other? That is if we are given that $s_1a = t_1b + d$ and $d|a$ and $d|b$. Can we find coefficients that satisfy $t_2b = s_2a + d$?

(REMEMBER: These are all natural numbers. However, the sketches of my proofs have been using subtraction even though it is not defined in my system.  We can easily eliminate subtraction from the proof by moving negative terms to the other side of the equation.  Furthermore when subtracting $k>0$ by $1$ we can state that there exists a number $l$ such that $l+1 = k$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\mathrm{gcd}(a, b) = d$, so one can write $a = a'd$ and $b = b'd$ such that $\mathrm{gcd}(a', b') = 1$. Now choose an natural number $k > \max\{\frac{t_1}{a'}, \frac{s_1}{b'}\}$ and define $t_2 = ka' - t_1$ and $s_2 = kb' - s_1$. Using the equation $s_1a = t_1b + d$ we achieve $s_1a' = t_1b' + 1$ and therefore
\begin{align*}
t_2b = (ka' - t_1)b'd = ka'b'd - t_1b'd &= ka'b'd - (s_1a' - 1)d\\
&= ka'b'd - s_1a'd + d\\
&= (kb' - s_1)a'd + d\\
&= s_2a + d.
\end{align*}